# How can I hide the output of command line in terminal window?

Tags: bash

Bellow is a simple code:

```
#!/bin/bash -ef
echo "Hello" > log.txt #saving the output of this command log.txt
command1 #this command running and showing it is output in terminal
command2 > log.txt #saving the output of this command log.txt
command3 #this command running and showing it is output in terminal
```

If I have in the script many commands. Can I hide the output of certain commands and leave this output showing in terminal window for the rest? and at the same time how can I save the output for all the commands ( showing output or not) in log.txt

Comment: You are doing it right..am i missing something here ?

Comment: @heemayl. Thanks! But this is for only one command line. If I have many commands in the script. How can I prevent the output of the commands from showing in terminal and instead recording it in one log file. If I add > log.txt in front of every command this will remove the output from the previous commands?

Comment: Use append redirection operator `>>`

Comment: In front of every command?

Comment: @don_crissti. Exactly. This is what I meant

Comment: @MJA: No, behind every command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily redirect output to a file like so:

```
exec 1> log.txt
echo -n "Hello" # Hello will be written to log.txt
# Some more commands here
# whose stdout will be
# written to log.txt
exec 1> /dev/tty # Redirect stdout back to your terminal
```

A more general way (in case your stdout wasn't the terminal and you want to restore it to what it originally was):

```
exec 3>&1 # Point a new filehandle to the current stdout
exec 1> log.txt 
echo -n "Hello" # Hello will be written to log.txt
# Some more commands here
# whose stdout will be
# written to log.txt
exec 1> &3 # Restore stdout to what it originally was
exec 3> &- # Close the temporary filehandle
```

Thanks to [Celada's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14034/celada) for pointing this out.

Comment: This is problematic if the original stdout was not the terminal. A true save&restore, or using a subshell (so you don't need to restore anything) would be preferable.

Comment: @Celada True. Thanks for the comment. I simply inferred from the OP's comments that stdout is already the terminal.

Comment: One should never assume this. Even if the person writing the script (the OP in this case) expects stdout to be the terminal, the person *using* the script (a different person) might run the script with output redirected elsewhere and expect it to stay redirected.

Comment: @Celada You are right. Does the update help?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant by a "true save&restore".

Comment: @Celada Great. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @JosephR. and Celada. This is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!